# List all subspaces of $ \ \mathbb{R}^3 \ $

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ \ T=\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_1 \\ 2x_2 \end{bmatrix} : \ x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R} \right\} \ $

(a) List all subspaces of $ \ \mathbb{R}^3 \ $

(b) Show that $ \ T \ $ is a subspace of $ \ \mathbb{R}^3 \ $ and Identify which one from your list in part (a) and sketch it.

**Answer:**

**Part (a)**

Any line or plane passing through origin is a subspace of $ \ \mathbb{R}^3 \ $

Intersection of any two subspaces are subspaces of $ \ \mathbb{R}^3 \ $

Also $ \ 0 \ \ and \ \ \mathbb{R}^3 \ $ are subspaces of $ \ \mathbb{R}^3 \ $.

**part (b)**

$ (x_1,x_1,2x_2)=x_1(1,1,0)+x_2(0,0,2) \ , \ \forall \ x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R} \ $

It is a plane passing through origin .

So  $ \ T \ $ is a subspace of $ \ \mathbb{R}^3 \ $.

**Am I right?**

Comment: $T$, being two-dimensional, is a plane (not a line).

Comment: Note that $(x_1,x_1,2x_2)=(0,0,0)+x_1(1,1,0)+x_2(0,0,2)$ where $(1,1,0)$ and $(0,0,2)$ are linearly independent and $\ x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}.$

Comment: How can I sketch the subspace T ?

Comment: What do you mean by "sketch the subspace"?

Comment: I mean the graph of T

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plane+(1,1,0)+(0,0,2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it isn't a line, since $T$ has dimension $2$ (that is it is spanned by two linearly independent vectors) it is a plane through the origin.

The cartesian equation $ax+by+cz=0$ can be found by

- $a+b=0$
- $2c=0$

that is

$$x-y=0$$

Comment: Can you sketch the subspace?

Comment: @yourmath From the cartesian equation we can easily deduce that it is a  vertical plane containing the $z$ axis and the line $y=x$ in the x-y plane.